# Maven web project groupId path is missing

Tags: maven

I am creating maven web project by running the following command:

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webpp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp`

This command creates my-webapp/src/main/resources and my-webapp/src/main/webapp folders.
But the groupId path: com.mycompany.app is missing.

Is in normal behaviour or may be I missed to do something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this really an `R` question?

Comment: I don't see `groupId` in [docs](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behavior only. Open your created pom.xml to view the group Id details.

It is very useful when you upload your project to the repository. Group Id is mainly used to differentiate your project from others project in the repository.

Please read the http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates